# Replace value from its description from a list c#

Tags: c#

I have a list(in txt file) that looks like this field:description

```
field20D.name = Reference
field20[101].name = Sender's Reference
field20[102].name = File Reference
field20[102_STP].name = File Reference
field20[103].name = Sender's Reference
```

The numbers in [] like 101,102 are messagetype.

How can i write the code so when i have a property with any value in that list, to get the equivalent description for it.

example: when a field has a value `"20D"` to build a string `"20D - Reference"`

Comment: and "20[101]" would be "20[101] - Sender's Reference" ?

Comment: The numbers in [] like 101,102 are messagetype. I have that info in my code too

Comment: What does your code have to do with your text file?

Comment: I just can't understand a thing from how you explaining the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good class that can do what you stated above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestConsoleProject
{
    public class WeirdLineFormatReader
    {
        public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ReadLines(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // split each line on the =
                string[] strLineArray = line.Split('=');

                // get the first and second values of the split line
                string field = strLineArray[0];
                string value = strLineArray[1];

                // remove the first field word
                field = field.Substring("field".Length);
                // remove the .name portion
                field = field.Replace(".name", "");
                // remove the surrounding white-space
                field = field.Trim();

                // remove all white space before/after the description
                value = value.Trim();

                yield return new Tuple<string, string>(field, value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here's a quick console project that will use the class to output your format to the console the way you want.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TestConsoleProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(args[0]);

            var reader = new WeirdLineFormatReader();

            var tuples = reader.ReadLines(lines);

            foreach (var tuple in tuples)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Just for the fun of it and also because I suspect you are only showing us a couple of the lines in a much larger text file; here's a format for unit testing when you find that you need to add more code to the ReadLines(string[]) method later.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Linq;
using TestConsoleProject;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFormatter_WithoutBrackets()
        {
            // Arrange
            var reader = new WeirdLineFormatReader();
            string[] lines = {
                "field20D.name = Reference"
            };

            // Act
            var tuples = reader.ReadLines(lines).ToList();

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(tuples[0].Item1, "20D", "Field 20D did not format correctly, Actual:" + tuples[0].Item1);
            Assert.AreEqual(tuples[0].Item2, "Reference", "Field 20D's description did not format correctly, Actual:" + tuples[0].Item2);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFormatter_WithBrackets()
        {
            // Arrange
            var reader = new WeirdLineFormatReader();
            string[] lines = {
                "field20[103].name = Sender's Reference"
            };

            // Act
            var tuples = reader.ReadLines(lines).ToList();

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(tuples[0].Item1, "20[103]", "Field 20[103] did not format correctly, Actual:" + tuples[0].Item1);
            Assert.AreEqual(tuples[0].Item2, "Sender's Reference", "Field 20[103]'s description did not format correctly, Actual:" + tuples[0].Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this unit test project you can quickly write new tests for edge cases that you discover. After you modify the `ReadLines()` method, you can re-run all the unit tests to see if you broke any of the older tests.

Comment: Updated it to use a lot less memory.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I see. Keeping all that memory for yourself, huh?

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo:

create a dictionary of key value pairs
split on carriage return
split on equals sign (can there be an equals sign in the value?)
regex the first half to get everything between 'field' and '.name', put that in the key
put the split from after the equals sign in the value

now you can reference your dictionary by key:

```
entry = myDictionary["20D"];
return $"{entry.Key} - {entry.value}";
```